# I need to change material UI helper text background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

you can see in the image below my background color is like gray am text field color is white when I show an error then that text field white color gets extended and the password error shows it's not looking good I need a set like text field white not get extend it error shown below in grey background

```
<TextField
  className={classes.textField}
  variant="outlined"
  id="outlined-basic"
  fullWidth
  type={values.hidden ? "password" : "text"}
  {...loginForm.getFieldProps("password")}
  name="password"
  error={loginForm.touched.password && loginForm.errors.password}
  helperText={loginForm.touched.password && loginForm.errors.password}
  placeholder="Password"
  InputProps={{
    endAdornment: (
      <InputAdornment position="end">
        <IconButton
          className="icon"
          aria-label="toggle password visibility"
          onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
          onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
          edge="end"
        >
          {values.hidden ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
        </IconButton>
      </InputAdornment>
    )
  }}
/>;
```

[image]

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-gizfo?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the `TextField` error color and other css properties here:

```
  textfield: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    "&  .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error": { //<--- here
      backgroundColor: "red",
      margin:0,
      paddingLeft: 10
    },
  },
```

Comment: No it's not coming properly

Comment: @HimanshuRathi did you tried with margin:0 to remove the white borders and adding some paddingLeft?

Comment: "&  .MuiFormHelperText-root." -> "&  .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error"  to use for both error state and not error state.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the FormHelperTextProps props to set style or class to the helper text props

```
<TextField
  ....
  FormHelperTextProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}}

/>
```

Also, if setting className does not work for you (since it works on the parent div) you may want to learn how to use classes props or InputProps props of TextField

https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/

Comment: Clear and simple answer. You were missing a quote around `transparent` so I've edited that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You over overide style of class MuiFormHelperText-root:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { InputAdornment } from "@material-ui/core";
import PersonIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Person";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& .MuiTextField-root": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200
    },
    "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": {
      color: "#000 !important"
    }
  },
  bg: {
    backgroundColor: "#7986cb"
  },
  textfield: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff"
  }
}));

export default function ValidationTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <div className={classes.bg}>
        <TextField
          className={classes.textfield}
          placeholder="Email"
          variant="outlined"
          fullWidth
          name="username"
          error
          helperText={"error!"}
          type="text"
          id="outlined-basic"
          InputProps={{
            endAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="end">
                <PersonIcon />
              </InputAdornment>
            )
          }}
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: how can I apply this in theme

Comment: I edited my code, we need to include the class MuiFormHelperText-root into the theme.

Answer (score 0):

This can also achieved in css file

```
 .MuiFormHelperText-root.Mui-error {
    opacity: 1;
    color: rgba(255, 109, 109, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    /*  background-image: url('../../../assets/error.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 2px;*/
 }
```

In jsx file,

```
 <FormHelperText id="component-helper-text">
              {validEmail ? ' ' : errorMessageEmail}
   </FormHelperText>
```